# NX Can't find a root directory while resolving a config file path

Tags: angular, unit-testing, command-line-interface, ts-jest, nx-monorepo

I'm running the following command: `nx test --project=<my_lib_name>`
and gets the following error:

**"NX Can't find a root directory while resolving a config file path"**

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**

my problem was that i've changed the library directory after i've created the library

**OLD:**

// project.json

```
   "options": {
      "jestConfig": "libs/my_lib_name/jest.config.ts",
       ...
      }
```

// jest.config.ts

```
export default {
    preset: '../../jest.preset.js',
    ...
    }
```

**NEW:**

// project.json

```
"options": {
   "jestConfig": "libs/feature-libraries/my_lib_name/jest.config.ts",
     ...
 }
```

// jest.config.ts

```
   export default {
      preset: '../../../jest.preset.js',
      ...
    }
```